# Intern Problem Statement for a bank

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, banking

I saw an intern opportunity in a bank in dubai. They have a defined problem statement to be solved in 2 months. They told us just 2 lines -

"Basically the problem is about name matching logic.
There are two fields (variables) – both are employer names, and it’s a free text field. So we need to write a program to match these two variables."

Can anyone help me in understanding it? Is it just a simple pattern matching stuff?
Any help/comments would be appreciated.

Comment: The problem statement is, unfortunately, not clear at all. Can you ask for clarification?

Comment: I have asked for it. But it seems they are in a hurry. It seems i will be given the clarification and asked about it in interviews itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what they are asking for:

They have two sources of related data, for example, one from an internal database, and the other from name card input.

Because the two fields are *free* text fields, there will be inconsistency. For example, `Nitin Garg`, or `Garg, Nitin`, or `Mr. Nitin Garg`, etc. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365283/regular-expression-to-search-for-gadaffi) is an extreme case of Gadaffi.

What you are supposed to do is to find a way to match all the names for a specific person together.

In short, match two pieces of data together by employer names, taking possible inconsistency into account.

Answer (score 2):

Once upon a time there was a nice simple answer to the problem of matching up names despite mis-spellings and different transliterations - Soundex. But people have put a lot of work into this problem, so now you should probably use the results of that work, which is built into databases and add-ons - some free. See [Fuzzy matching using T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921978/fuzzy-matching-using-t-sql) and http://anastasiosyal.com/archive/2009/01/11/18.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163731.aspx