# Find similar words by pronunciation - algorithms, approaches, libraries

Tags: c++, ruby, search, text, text-processing

By 'table' it should find 'cable', 'tabular'  etc.
E.g. like you type the word in type in dictionary and it says may be you wanted word1, word2 which are close in spell to the one I typed.

What is the name of algorithms and approaches used? Any libraries providing the functionality (C/C++, Ruby)?

I need to search by word (dictionary-like application), no phrases, sentences, etc.

Comment: Libraries would obviously depend on the language you're using, so including that in the question would help to narrow down suggestions to those that are actually useful to you.

Comment: Updated to C/C++, Ruby but any other would be interesting to have a look on how it works.

Comment: Related question: [Regular expression to search for Gadaffi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365283/regular-expression-to-search-for-gadaffi)

Answer (score 7):

As well as **Soundex** which was developed as far back as **1918** there are also [**Metaphone** and **Double Metaphone**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) which were developed in the **1990s** and **2000s** respectively specifically to be be improvements over Soundex.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for **soundex**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex
The Wikipedia page list libraries for several programming languages.