# Can regex be used to validate numbers OUTSIDE a range of specific numbers?

Tags: php, regex

I have referred to several SO webpages for the answer to my question, but I keep reading that regex should not be used for validating numbers which are less than or greater than a certain range. I want to   ensure that a user enters numbers within the following ranges: 11--20 and 65-100. Anything less than 11 will not be allowed, anything between 21 and 64 will not be allowed and anything from 101 above will not be allowed. I realize I can write something like

```
                    if ($num <=10 and $num >= 21 and $num <=64 and $num >=101) {
                    $num = "";
                    $numErr = "Number must be within  specified ranges";
                    }
```

But what I really want is to use regex to preclude the range of numbers I do not want from being entered  but I have not seen any satisfactory answers on SO. Can someone please help?

Comment: you might be able to write such regex, but will definitely be less readable than this.

Comment: The regex approach will not scale to more varied ranges. For a more extreme example, look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5365283/1233508 .

Comment: *Can* regex be used, yes. *Should* regex be used, **no**.

Answer (score 4):

The regex would be less readable but like

```
/^(1[1-9]|20|6[5-9]|[7-9][0-9]|100)$/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/kF1hM0/4)

Comment: You need to surround the alternatives in (), if you want `^$` to work correctly: `^(..|.....|..)$`.

Comment: @DCoder Yup. Edited in answer

Comment: nu11p01n73R, I appreciate your help. Thanks.